# How do I use Zathura after Homebrew installation?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, pdf, books

Command line newbie here. I was looking for a PDF/EPUB reader that didn't annihilate my retinas, and looked like Zathura was a good option since others didn't seem to have dark mode. I installed Zathura with Homebrew, but I am at a loss as to how to actually use it to view EPUBS and PDFs.

I found where it's located in the directory (/usr/local/opt/zathura), but that's as far as I've gotten and I still can't run the application.

Feel like I'm probably missing something super obvious, and in typical stackexchange manner someone will scold me for it. As long as you also tell me what to do that's fine lol.